# Visual Studio Code remote building on Raspberry virtual machine

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, virtualbox, raspbian, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to setup a remote building C++ environment from a host Ubuntu 20.04 machine to a Raspbian machine virtualized on the same with Virtualbox.
IDE is Visual Studio Code + SSH plugins. When I try to connect to the Raspberry VM through Ubuntu terminal everything goes fine through a simple "ssh pi@192.168.1.2" and entering password.
When I try to connect through VSC the remote server is properly downloaded but cannot be started.
I'm a noob on this matter so I'm sure there's some setting wrong or so, but after googling all the day I saw not able to find a fix.
Here below the log with the error:

```
[21:44:37.026] Log Level: 2
[21:44:37.030] remote-ssh@0.82.1
[21:44:37.030] linux x64
[21:44:37.035] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+192.168.1.7", attempt 1
[21:44:37.036] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true
[21:44:37.036] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[21:44:37.036] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[21:44:37.036] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[21:44:37.037] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[21:44:37.037] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[21:44:37.037] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[21:44:37.037] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[21:44:37.038] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[21:44:37.038] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[21:44:37.038] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[21:44:37.038] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[21:44:37.038] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[21:44:37.038] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[21:44:37.051] SSH Resolver called for host: 192.168.1.7
[21:44:37.051] Setting up SSH remote "192.168.1.7"
[21:44:37.056] Acquiring local install lock: /tmp/vscode-remote-ssh-7b5c057e-install.lock
[21:44:37.060] Looking for existing server data file at /home/paolo/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-7b5c057e-92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9-0.82.1/data.json
[21:44:37.061] Using commit id "92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9" and quality "stable" for server
[21:44:37.065] Install and start server if needed
[21:44:37.069] PATH: /home/paolo/perl5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
[21:44:37.070] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[21:44:37.081] > OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

[21:44:37.093] askpass server listening on /run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-2541d2ea863d2a60e4fa3b327ca41d38a067f84e.sock
[21:44:37.093] Spawning local server with {"serverId":1,"ipcHandlePath":"/run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-80e897393adb3aac6d825098f15d1421c1862347.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","37285","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","192.168.1.7"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscode-server","dataFilePath":"/home/paolo/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-7b5c057e-92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9-0.82.1/data.json"}
[21:44:37.094] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh","SHELL":"/bin/bash","DISPLAY":":1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/home/paolo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/snap/code/100/usr/share/code/code","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"--ms-enable-electron-run-as-node","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/home/paolo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-2541d2ea863d2a60e4fa3b327ca41d38a067f84e.sock"}
[21:44:37.113] Spawned 29361
[21:44:37.296] > local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=29369
[21:44:37.302] stderr> OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
[21:44:37.317] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:tSarh0zJfXffabI0vaON0Y83V/j0IrfuLv86hJLLDAg
[21:44:37.495] Got askpass request: {"request":"pi@192.168.1.7's password:"}
[21:44:37.496] Showing password prompt
[21:44:37.497] Listening for interwindow password on /run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-17f0f747246fef8bcee3f15146da59f995285a39.sock
[21:44:37.497] Writing password prompt to globalState
[21:44:42.245] Got password response
[21:44:42.246] Interactor gave response: ************
[21:44:42.246] Cleaning up other-window auth server
[21:44:42.302] stderr> Authenticated to 192.168.1.7 ([192.168.1.7]:22).
[21:44:42.338] > Linux raspberry 4.19.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28) x86_64
> 
> The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
> the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
> individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
> 
> Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
> permitted by applicable law.
[21:44:42.348] > ready: a4efe3e1eaf0
[21:44:42.349] > Linux 4.19.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28)
[21:44:42.350] Platform: linux
[21:44:42.351] > /bin/bash
[21:44:42.351] Shell: bash
[21:44:42.351] Creating bash subshell inside "bash"
[21:44:42.354] > bash version:  5.0.3(1)-release
[21:44:42.369] > a4efe3e1eaf0: running
[21:44:42.401] > Acquiring lock on /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9/vscode-remote-lock.pi.92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9
[21:44:42.406] > Installing to /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9...
[21:44:42.409] > a4efe3e1eaf0%%1%%
[21:44:42.412] > Downloading with wget
[21:44:55.355] > Download complete
[21:44:55.359] > a4efe3e1eaf0%%2%%
> tar --version:
[21:44:55.360] > tar (GNU tar) 1.30
> Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
> 
> Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
[21:44:57.288] > Checking /home/pi/.vscode-server/.92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9.log and /home/pi/.vscode-server/.92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9.pid for a running server
[21:44:57.301] > Starting server with command... /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9/bin/code-server --start-server --host=127.0.0.1 --accept-server-license-terms --enable-remote-auto-shutdown --port=0 --telemetry-level all   &> "/home/pi/.vscode-server/.92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9.log" < /dev/null
> printenv:
[21:44:57.303] >     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
>     NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
>     PWD=/home/pi
>     LOGNAME=pi
>     XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
>     HOME=/home/pi
>     LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>     VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/home/pi/.vscode-server
>     SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.12 50872 192.168.1.7 22
>     XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
>     PIGPIO_ADDR=fe80::1%usb0
>     GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY=pigpio
>     USER=pi
>     SHLVL=1
>     XDG_SESSION_ID=12
>     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
>     SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.12 50872 22
>     LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
>     PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
>     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
>     MAIL=/var/mail/pi
>     OLDPWD=/home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9
>     TEXTDOMAIN=Linux-PAM
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
[21:44:57.306] stderr> rm: 
[21:44:57.307] stderr> cannot remove '/home/pi/.vscode-server/.92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9.token': No such file or directory
[21:44:57.309] > Spawned remote server: 12918
[21:44:57.315] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:57.354] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:57.392] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:57.521] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:57.559] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:57.597] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:57.636] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:57.681] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:57.720] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:57.761] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:57.800] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:57.838] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:57.879] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:57.917] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:57.957] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:57.996] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.033] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.075] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.114] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.153] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.190] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.231] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.269] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.309] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.351] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.392] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.431] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.472] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.512] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.551] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.591] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.630] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.669] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.710] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.747] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.786] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.824] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.864] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.903] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.942] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:58.981] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.021] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.063] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.103] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.143] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.181] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.220] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.259] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.300] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.339] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.378] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.417] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.455] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.492] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.531] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.568] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.606] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.646] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.684] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.725] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.763] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.802] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.842] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.880] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.919] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.959] > Waiting for server log...
[21:44:59.999] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.039] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.079] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.119] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.160] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.199] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.239] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.279] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.317] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.358] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.398] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.435] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.473] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.512] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.553] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.592] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.631] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.670] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.710] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.749] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.789] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.829] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.868] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.908] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.946] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:00.984] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.024] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.064] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.104] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.145] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.183] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.223] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.261] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.300] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.340] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.379] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.417] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.456] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.493] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.528] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.566] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.606] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.643] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.680] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.718] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.758] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.794] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.829] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.864] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.907] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.945] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:01.981] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.017] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.056] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.093] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.132] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.170] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.209] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.246] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.284] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.332] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.368] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.408] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.446] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.485] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.523] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.561] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.599] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.639] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.679] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.718] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.759] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.798] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.836] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.875] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.913] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.952] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:02.992] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.032] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.072] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.111] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.151] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.191] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.230] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.270] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.309] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.347] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.386] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.427] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.466] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.505] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.545] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.584] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.624] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.664] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.703] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.742] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.779] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.818] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.858] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.896] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.936] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:03.975] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.017] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.056] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.095] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.133] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.172] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.209] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.247] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.287] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.327] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.368] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.407] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.448] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.488] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.529] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.568] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.605] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.643] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.682] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.721] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.759] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.801] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.840] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.878] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.917] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.957] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:04.995] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.034] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.073] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.112] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.151] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.191] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.230] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.271] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.310] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.348] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.387] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.425] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.463] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.507] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.548] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.588] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.628] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.666] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.705] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.744] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.781] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.820] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.857] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.895] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.933] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:05.974] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.013] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.053] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.092] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.132] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.170] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.208] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.245] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.283] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.324] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.363] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.399] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.438] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.477] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.517] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.556] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.592] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.629] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.667] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.706] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.744] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.783] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.821] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.859] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.898] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.938] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:06.977] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.016] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.055] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.093] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.133] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.172] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.212] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.251] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.290] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.331] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.372] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.411] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.451] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.489] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.528] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.569] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.608] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.647] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.685] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.725] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.764] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.804] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.843] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.882] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.921] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:07.960] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.001] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.041] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.083] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.123] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.163] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.203] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.239] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.278] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.316] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.355] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.393] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.432] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.470] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.511] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.550] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.589] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.627] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.666] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.705] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.742] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.781] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.821] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.860] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.900] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.939] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:08.978] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.020] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.059] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.100] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.139] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.178] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.217] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.259] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.299] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.339] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.378] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.419] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.460] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.499] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.537] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.576] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.616] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.656] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.695] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.735] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.774] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.814] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.853] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.892] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.930] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:09.969] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.008] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.047] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.084] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.125] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.163] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.204] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.240] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.281] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.320] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.359] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.397] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.435] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.474] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.514] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.555] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.598] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.639] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.677] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.716] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.756] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.796] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.835] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.873] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.913] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.950] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:10.989] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.028] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.068] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.108] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.148] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.187] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.226] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.267] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.307] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.346] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.386] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.424] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.466] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.504] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.543] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.583] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.623] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.663] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.701] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.741] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.780] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.819] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.859] > Waiting for server log...
[21:45:11.896] >  
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
>  
[21:45:11.906] > Server did not start successfully. Full server log at /home/pi/.vscode-server/.92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9.log >>>
[21:45:11.906] > /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9/bin/code-server: 12: /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9/bin/code-server: /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9/node: not found
[21:45:11.907] > <<< End of server log
> a4efe3e1eaf0: start
> exitCode==32==
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId==debian==
> arch==x86_64==
> tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult==success==
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime==12947==
> installTime==1917==
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime==14589==
> a4efe3e1eaf0: end
[21:45:11.907] Received install output: 
exitCode==32==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==debian==
arch==x86_64==
tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
platform==linux==
unpackResult==success==
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime==12947==
installTime==1917==
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime==14589==

[21:45:11.909] Terminating local server
[21:45:11.910] Resolver error: Error: Non è stato possibile avviare il server di VS Code.
    at Function.ServerInstallError (/home/paolo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:585153)
    at f (/home/paolo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:579401)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (/home/paolo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:582426)
    at Object.e [as tryInstallWithLocalServer] (/home/paolo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:624370)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async /home/paolo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:643503
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (/home/paolo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:647221)
    at async /home/paolo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:622842
    at async T (/home/paolo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:619348)
    at async Object.t.resolveWithLocalServer (/home/paolo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:622457)
    at async Object.t.resolve (/home/paolo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:644831)
    at async /home/paolo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:727005
[21:45:11.918] ------




[21:45:11.919] Local server exit: 15
```

Hope this may help to understand what's wrong.....

Answer (score 1):

If this is due to the raspberry pi vm printing out 'aarch64' when running command `uname -m`, could be because the wrong version of vs remote server is being installed.

Installing the `armv7l` arch of the vs remote server manually worked for me.

I modified and used the script from: https://gist.github.com/b01/0a16b6645ab7921b0910603dfb85e4fb

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

# Auto-Get the latest commit sha via command line.
get_latest_release() {
    tag=$(curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/${1}/releases/latest" | # Get latest release from GitHub API
          grep '"tag_name":'                                              | # Get tag line
          sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/'                                    ) # Pluck JSON value

    tag_data=$(curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/${1}/git/ref/tags/${tag}")

    sha=$(echo "${tag_data}"           | # Get latest release from GitHub API
          grep '"sha":'                | # Get tag line
          sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/' ) # Pluck JSON value

    sha_type=$(echo "${tag_data}"           | # Get latest release from GitHub API
          grep '"type":'                    | # Get tag line
          sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/'      ) # Pluck JSON value

    if [ "${sha_type}" != "commit" ]; then
        combo_sha=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/${1}/git/tags/${sha}" | # Get latest release from GitHub API
              grep '"sha":'                                                     | # Get tag line
              sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/'                                      ) # Pluck JSON value

        # Remove the tag sha, leaving only the commit sha;
        # this won't work if there are ever more than 2 sha,
        # and use xargs to remove whitespace/newline.
        sha=$(echo "${combo_sha}" | sed -E "s/${sha}//" | xargs)
    fi

    printf "${sha}"
}

ARCH="x64"
U_NAME=$(uname -m)

# Raspberry pi 4b needs armv7l (armhf), but uname is specified as aarch64 (arm64) so I modified this part.
if [ "${U_NAME}" = "aarch64" ]; then
    ARCH="armhf"
fi

archive="vscode-server-linux-${ARCH}.tar.gz"
owner='microsoft'
repo='vscode'
commit_sha=$(get_latest_release "${owner}/${repo}")

if [ -n "${commit_sha}" ]; then
    echo "will attempt to download VS Code Server version = '${commit_sha}'"

    # Download VS Code Server tarball to tmp directory.
    curl -L "https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:${commit_sha}/server-linux-${ARCH}/stable" -o "/tmp/${archive}"

    # Make the parent directory where the server should live.
    # NOTE: Ensure VS Code will have read/write access; namely the user running VScode or container user.
    mkdir -vp ~/.vscode-server/bin/"${commit_sha}"

    # Extract the tarball to the right location.
    tar --no-same-owner -xzv --strip-components=1 -C ~/.vscode-server/bin/"${commit_sha}" -f "/tmp/${archive}"
else
    echo "could not pre install vscode server"
fi
```

So, what I did:

1. `rm -rf ~/.vscode-server` # remove existing vscode-server
2. ^create an sh file and copy paste the above script
3. run the script.
4. VS code remote should work

Just a guess but I figure is that for RPis that are showing as arch `aarch64`, downloads the `arm64` version when really, it should download the `armv7l` arch, which is `armhf`.

Hope this helps someone avoid 2 hours of headbashing :P